# The type or namespace AmazonS3 could not be found

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm attempting to upload a file to my Amazon S3 bucket and all the code examples give me something like this:
///////////////////////////////////

```
using System;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
string accessKey = "put your access key here!";
string secretKey = "put your secret key here!";

AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
config.ServiceURL = "objects.dreamhost.com";

AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
        accessKey,
        secretKey,
        config
        );
```

////////////////////////////////////
The problem is that the Amazon S3 client doesn't find the assembly or reference and when I click on the options to help bind it the only option that pops up is to generate a class for AmazonS3. I have the amazon aws for sdk.net installed through nuget. Besides "AmazonS3", everything else references fine.
////////////////UPDATE///////////////////
This has not been fun, it has wasted away the first half of my day :( I'm going to post this so that maybe someone else can use the code. I don't know why I couldn't find anything on the internet about it. Here it is:

```
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
        config.ServiceURL = "http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com(your service URL)";
        Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3 s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client("Id", "Key", config);
        String S3_KEY = "Test.txt";
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();

        request.BucketName = "Your Bucket Name";
        request.Key = S3_KEY;
        request.ContentBody = "This is body of S3 object.";
        s3Client.PutObject(request);
```

Comment: i believe you need to find that assembly reference and add it into the project otherwise there wouldnt be a way for it to compile without having access to the assembly that has the reference. do a search on your local drive for it ir download the SDK (if available) instead of nuget. Maybe nuget didnt add it?

Comment: I reinstalled the sdk independently and it still didn't work. I manually remodified the code which took a while but it works now. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears in the AWS template console app using the AWS SDK, they do not actually call AmazonS3 class directly. What they do is call the interface IAmazonS3 instead. Try replacing AmazonS3 with IAmazonS3 and it should work.